# Cannot update a component (`Back`) while rendering a different component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I know this question has been answered many times, but I have looked through all the answers and none of them look like my case. I have a JSX component which is basically a header, and in it I have placed another JSX component which is a backpress button. In that backpress button, I have an SVG which is wrapped inside of a Pressable. Now I want the color of the SVG to change when pressed. To achieve that, I have the following code:

```
function Back({style, onPress}) {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('white');

  // const Change = useCallback(async (colour) => {
  //   setColor(colour);
  // }, [color]);

    useEffect(async () => {
    if (pressed) {
    await  setColor('#c5e2e8');
    } else {
    await  setColor('white');
    }
  }, [color, pressed]);

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={({pressed}) => {
        pressed ? setPressed(true) : setPressed(false);
        [style];
      }}
      onPress={onPress}>
      <Svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        height={36}
        width={36}
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        fill={color}>
        <Path d="somerandompath" />
      </Svg>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

The problem is that when I press on the back button, I get the warning *Cannot update a component (`Back`) while rendering a different component*

As you can see, I tried to put it inside an useEffect. However, it did not help solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have tried to solve this for many hours, and 5 mins after posting here I managed to solve it! Here is the answer:

Make use of the OnPressIn and OnPressOut events of the Pressable component. I removed the entire styles. Here is the new code:

```
function Back({style, onPress}) {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('white');

  const onPressIn = async () => {
    await setColor('#c5e2e8');
  }
  
  const onPressOut = async () => {
    await setColor('white');
  }


  return (
    <Pressable
      onPressIn={onPressIn}
      onPressOut={onPressOut}
      onPress={onPress}>
      <Svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1"
        height={36}
        width={36}
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        fill={color}>
        <Path d="somepathcode" />
      </Svg>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```